# Boolean function of digital comparator

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, boolean-algebra, binary

The boolean equation or function for a binary digital comparator is **(A3&~B3)|| (x3&A2&~B2)|| (x3&x2&A1&~B1)|| (x3&x2&x1&A0&~B0)**.

This equation is considered to be the correct digital comparator.

But according to me **(A3&~B3)|| (A2&~B2)|| (A1&~B1)|| (A0&~B0)** gives the same result as the previous mentioned equation.

I can’t figure out the reason for adding xi with every comparison, it just makes the circuit more complex.

Comment: could you define what you `~` and `^` mean? and how their associativity rules are?

Comment: ~ is used for NOT. ^ is used for AND. || is used for OR.

Comment: Associativity: does OR bind stronger than NOT? does AND bind stronger than OR?  Honestly, could you maybe rewrite this with enough parenthesis to make clear what you mean? Also, since `^` is usually the symbol for XOR, you **must** add the definition of your symbols to the text of your questions by **editing** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should be using '&'for representing and operation, rather than '^' as the latter is usually used for xor operation. This creates a lot of confusion.

The Boolean expression given by : A3^~B3|| x3^A2^~B2|| x3^x2^A1^~B1|| x3^x2^x1^A0^~B0. is correct one and the latter one is incorrect. You can consider A=0100 and B=1000.

Now according to your proposed expression, The result will be 1, suggesting A is greater than B, which is incorrect. This is because for n bit number comparison, while comparing nth bit, it must be made sure that the previous n-1 bits (from MSB side are equal), else there is no point carrying out further evaluation.

The first expression, if x3=1, it means that A3 and B3 are equal, so now we compare A2 and B2. If x2=1, meaning A2 and B2 are equal, so comparing A1 and B1 and so on. Therefore your expression is incomplete .

Thanks